# TypeError: Expect is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Why do I get a `TypeError: expect is not a function` when running this test file?

I've installed mocha and chai locally and run the test via `yarn run test` which runs simply `"test": "mocha"`.

```
var chai = require('chai')
var expect = chai.expect()

describe('Array', function () {
  describe('#indexOf()', function () {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function () {
      expect([1, 2, 3].indexOf(4)).to.be.equal(-1)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When setting `expect`, you need to do this:

```
var expect = chai.expect
```

You are evaluating the function with `()`, which is not correct [according to the documentation](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#expect)

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the result of calling the function *chai.expect* to your variable *chai*, which do not make sense.

Instead, you need to assign a reference to this function, like this:

```
var expect = chai.expect;
```

(without the parentheses)